# Recording MySQL executions to script file in WIndows?

Tags: mysql, windows

for my database systems assignment after we create somethings in mySQL we need to record our executions in a script file to print off to show we actually did it.

I know how to create a script file in Linux but I cannot see how to do one in Windows?

Comment: maybe interesting?  Record from mysql cli? see: --tee - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you